# Сервер Apache и aspx

Tags: apache, aspx

Можно ли на сервере с Apache нормально открыть aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если под открытием `aspx` вы подразумеваете запуск `ASP.NET` приложений, то да, это возможно.

Для этого используется компонент `mod_mono`.

**UPD.**

Раньше разрабатывался `mod_aspdotnet`, специально для запуска `ASP.NET` под apache 2 на windows-платформе. В отличие от `mod_mono` он использует родной рантайм.

Вот [тут](http://lifeofageekadmin.com/running-asp-net-on-apache-2-2/) нагуглился какой-то мануал по настройке, вот тут можно скачать сам [`mod_aspdotnet`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mod-aspdotnet/).

Comment: Не подскажите где его взять

Comment: - http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/l-Mono_10/index.html
- http://library.linode.com/frameworks/mod-mono/debian-5-lenny

Comment: А под windows

Comment: А зачем? IIS есть в всех современных версиях windows.

Comment: 2003 года у меня да и нехочеться IIS пользоваться мне на apache нравиться